# C++ - How to get a binary representation of a decimal number

Tags: c++, binary, decimal

I'm trying to get the binary representation of a decimal number. I have looked all over the internet but could not find anything useful.

Can anyone provide me with sample code?

Note that I want it to run on both 32-bit and 64-bit architecture.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried something already? If you did, what was the problem?

Comment: The question you should ask yourself is *How can I do this by hand?*. If you don't understand the problem, you can't write a program to solve it.

Comment: "Not anything useful" equates "code I could copy and paste"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just isolate the bits one by one, starting from the highest, and print the appropriate character:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void print_binary(unsigned x)
{
    for (int i = sizeof(x) * CHAR_BIT; i--; )
    {
        putchar('0' + ((x >> i) & 1));
    }
}

int main()
{
    print_binary(123);
}
```

If you want the result in a string instead of printed to the console, I'm sure you can adjust the code.

Comment: Thanks mate, this works. Is there anyway to do this without assuming that it's running on a 32-bit computer? (or 64-bit)

Comment: Sure, just replace the constant 31 by a portable formula, see my edit.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 1):

Get the bits from the bottom up.
Then reverse the string when done.

```
string bits(long n)
{
   string tmp ;

   while ( n ) { tmp << ( n & 1 ) ? "1" : "0" ;  n >>= 1 ; }
   tmp= reverse( tmp) ;
   return tmp ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try William Clinger's paper "How to read floating point numbers accurately".

Comment: http://www.cesura17.net/~will/Professional/Research/Papers/howtoread.pdf